# Регулярное выражение на проверку строки похожую на admin

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Нужно написать на java проверку строки, так чтобы нельзя было сделать admin, @dmin, admln и так далее. Для строки можно использовать только символы из таблицы ASCII, то есть никакого utf-8

Comment: @Dm1 подходит или нельзя? Нужен критерий похожести.

Comment: @becouse Я просто не знаю как сделат так, чтобы он искал все вариации, так как можно написать admln и это я обработаю, но в то же время можно совмещать разные варинанты например `@dmln` и так далее

Comment: @Splierash, компьютер он такой. Он не может сам придумать все варианты. Их придется задать либо перечислением либо системой правил.

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
Pattern.compile("^[a@]dm[il]n$").matcher(str).find()
```

Если вернёт `true`, значит совпало и не пропускаем такую строку.